# What does root means in terminal?

Tags: terminal, root

What is the difference between the following:

I have 2 accounts in my OS, **baron** and **root**

I login with baron account, then run the command `sudo -s`

```
baron@linux:~@ sudo -s 
[sudo] password for baron:
root@linux:~@/home/baron#
```

I logout, then login with root account and terminal shows:

```
root@linux:~@
```

So why the terminal is showing the same when I login with different accounts?

Comment: To clarify: are you asking why the prompts for user root are different depending on how you log in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prompt shows the user, hostname & current dir

```
user@hostname:/current/dir $
```

When you execute the `sudo` command as a normal user (**baron** in your case), you're giving the system an order to make "something" as root or with root privileges. [See root definition](http://www.linfo.org/root.html)

With the `-s` option, you're giving the order to become `root` user with an interactive shell environment since there's no command specified

--From `man sudo`

```
-s [command]
               The -s (shell) option runs the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell as specified in the password database.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution
               via the shell's -c option.  If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.
```

Then, when you login as `root`, the main account will be **root**, so you don't need to execute `sudo` at all